# Assert API result response

Tags: python, selenium

How i can assert that birthday == 1990-07-11 ?

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "birthDate": "1990-07-11",
            "cardNumber": "0QBD0040267646",
            "cellPhone": "(514) 333-4444",
            "city": "Brossard",
            "email": "farouk.rahem@bciti.com",
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "success": True,
    "total": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's assert

```py
d = { "count": 1, "results": [ { "birthDate": "1990-07-11", "cardNumber": "0QBD0040267646", "cellPhone": "(514) 333-4444", "city": "Brossard", "email": "farouk.rahem@bciti.com", } ], "start": 0, "success": True, "total": 1 }

assert d['results'][0]['birthDate'] == '1990-07-11'
```

You could read a fast [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/assertions_in_python.htm) about asserts in python.

Answer (score 0):

That is a dictionary, with a key `results` that is a list of further dictionaries, the first of which has a key `birthDate`.  Therefore:

```
assert myobject['results'][0]['birthDate'] == '1990-07-11'
```